# Get Index of an element/ element by index in List of Lists

Tags: list, loops, indexing, prolog

How could I achieve something similar to the `nth0/3` predicate on a list of lists ?

I would like to be able to tell what is the index of an element in a list of lists but only interested in the  inner list index. What I mean is lets say I have the following predicate `indexOf([[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [g,h]], d, Index)` and it returns `Index=0` because d is the first element of the inner list. 
`indexOf([[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [g,h]], c, Index)` should return `Index=2` since it is the 3rd element of the inner list.

What I have done so far is the following:

```
iterateOuter([]).

iterateOuter([[H|T]|LIST], Elem,Idx):-indexOf([H|T],Elem, Idx2),(Idx is Idx2;iterateOuter(LIST, Elem,Idx)).

indexOf([_|Tail], Element, Index):-indexOf(Tail, Element, Index1), Index is Index1+1. 

indexOf([Element|_], Element, 0).
```

if I invoke `iterateOuter([[a,b,c],[r,t,o]],c,Ind).`

It will give me `Ind = 2` and that's fine but if I say:
`iterateOuter([[a,b,c],[r,t,o]],r,Ind).`

it will simply give me false since it is only giving results on the first inner list.

Comment: What if the element is in more than one inner list?

Comment: Good point, sorry I forgot to add In that case I would want 2 results same as nth0 with a simple list.

Comment: @user3009573 Out of curiosity, what is the application you have in mind that such that the index of the element in the sublist is important but you don't need to know which sublist the element is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `nth0/3` already, you have all you need:

```
?- Xss = [[a,b,c],[r,t,o]], nth0(I, Xss, Xs), nth0(J, Xs, c).
   Xss = ["abc","rto"], I = 0, Xs = "abc", J = 2
;  false.
?- Xss = [[a,b,c],[r,t,o]], nth0(I, Xss, Xs), nth0(J, Xs, r).
   Xss = ["abc","rto"], I = 1, Xs = "rto", J = 0
;  false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only interested in the index of the inner list, you can just use `member/2` instead of `nth0/3` to get the sublist, as False suggested. Each sublist is a member of the list Ls, so you only need to find if E is the nth element of a member:

```
nth_of_a_sublist(N, Ls, E) :-
    member(L, Ls),
    nth0(N, L, E).
```

To check for the nth_of_a_sublist on all lists, you can use `findall/3`.

But False's solution is nicer, I think, because it gives you the index of the list that contains the element, which you can ignore if you don't need it.